# How to change different substrings in a string?

Tags: regex, kotlin, stringbuilder

I have a file with a certain number of lines.
I need to find all double letters and change the second letter to the one that corresponds to it in the map.
Case of replaced letters should be kept.
Example: 
`"kotlIn is a functional programming Language"`
 should become 
`"kotlYn is a functionol programmyng Longuage"`

```
fun changeChar(inputFileName: String, outputFileName: String) {
    val outputStream = File(outputFileName).bufferedWriter()
    val charsRegex = "([klmn][aei])".toRegex(setOf(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE))
    val validChars = mapOf('a' to 'o', 'e' to 'u', 'i' to 'y')
    File(inputFileName).forEachLine { line ->
        val sb = StringBuilder(line).replace(charsRegex, /*here is my difficulty*/)
        outputStream.write(sb)
        outputStream.newLine()
    }
    outputStream.close()
}
```

I spent many hours, but could not find solutions on the Internet and the standard Kotlin library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idiomatic solution would be to transform the matched string using the [`replace(...) { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) overload that accepts a lambda to handle each [`MatchResult`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/index.html#matchresult):

```
val charsRegex = "[klmn][aei]".toRegex(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
val validChars = mapOf('a' to 'o', 'e' to 'u', 'i' to 'y')

val result = line.replace(charsRegex) {
    val vowel = it.value[1]
    val validLetter = validChars.getValue(vowel.toLowerCase())
    val validCaseLetter = if (vowel.isLowerCase()) validLetter else validLetter.toUpperCase()
    it.value.take(1) + validCaseLetter
}
```

<sup>[(runnable sample)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Without any regex:

```
val validChars = mapOf('a' to 'o', 'e' to 'u', 'i' to 'y')
val chars = validChars.plus(validChars.map { it.key.toUpperCase() to it.value.toUpperCase() }.toMap())

var pattern = "klmn"
pattern = pattern.plus(pattern.toUpperCase())

val str = "kotlIn is a functional programming Language"
val result = str.mapIndexed { i, c ->
    if (i > 0) { if (pattern.contains(str[i -1])) chars.getOrDefault(c, c) else c } else c
}.joinToString("")
println(result)
```

will print:

> kotlYn is a functionol programmyng Longuage

Comment: This is not what i need. I need the value to change only at the letter after `klmn`. Like in my pattern `"([klmn][aei])"`. And then each `aei` symbol was replaced with the corresponding one in the map `val validChars = mapOf('a' to 'o', 'e' to 'u', 'i' to 'y')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val str = "kotlIn is a functional programming Language"
    val validChars = mapOf("a" to "o", "e" to "u", "i" to "y" )
    val charsRegex = "(?=(.))([klmn][aei])(?<=(.))".toRegex(setOf(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE))
    val found = charsRegex.findAll(str)
    var newStr= str
    found.forEach { f ->
        val m = f.value.toLowerCase()
        val idx = f.range
        val k = m.substring(1)
        val repStr = m.substring(0,1) + validChars.get(k)?.toUpperCase()
        newStr= newStr.replaceRange(idx,repStr)
       // println("$m found at indexes: $idx  ${validChars.get(k)} ${newStr}" )
     }
    println( "NewStr = ${newStr}")
}
```

Prints

```
NewStr = kotlYn is a functionOl programmYng lOnguage
```

PS: I'm not that good at Kotlin, but I think you can tweak it a little to get the accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [replace](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) which takes a transform lambda as hotkey proposed as well. But I would change the regex to have two groups.

- The first group is a positive lookbehind which means that it will be matched but not captured, since the first letter does not have to be replaced
- The second group will be captured, since the second letter has to be replaced by another character

Code:

```
fun replaceInvalidPairs(line: String): String {
    val charsRegex = "(?<=[klmn])([aei])".toRegex(setOf(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE))
    val validChars = mapOf('a' to 'o', 'e' to 'u', 'i' to 'y')

    return charsRegex.replace(line) {
        val secondLetter = it.groupValues.first().first()
        val replacement = validChars[secondLetter.toLowerCase()]!!
        (if (secondLetter.isUpperCase()) replacement.toUpperCase() else replacement).toString()
    }
}
```

Result:

> kotlYn is a functionol programmyng Longuage